# Sound Effect Won't Play (XCode/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I am following through an old tutorial and I think with the changes in xcode and swift this code is now no longer usable, but i am not sure. Would love some help.

Declaring constant for the audio effect

```
let cannonSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("cannon.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Calling the audio effect within my funtion

```
let hotdogSequence = SKAction.sequence([cannonSound, moveHotdog, deleteHotdog])
    hotdog.run(hotdogSequence)
```

For more info I am using SpriteKit in Xcode and this code is contained within GameScene.swift file.

Update:
The error I receive is

**2017-03-30 00:52:43.631 Ballpark Weiner[95999:1983181] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "cannon.wav"**

The game doesn't crash just no sound plays

Comment: nothing has changed, what is the error? or what happened when the sound is supposed to play? Are you sure the code is getting hit? You are nothing giving us enough information to help you

Comment: Hi The error I receive is 

**2017-03-30 00:52:43.631 Ballpark Weiner[95999:1983181] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "cannon.wav"**

The game doesn't crash just no sound plays

Comment: usually when I get that error it means that the sound file is not included in the project, or name slightly different (case sensitive) or the sound file is corrupt

Comment: I've checked the name and it looks good, I will try with a couple other files. 

But from a code standpoint I am on the right track then, no issues there.

Comment: No the syntax is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message usually means that the file cannot be found in your project or might be corrupt.

You should check that the file is actually copied into your project and is spelled correctly. Its case sensitive so if the actual file is called "Cannon.wav" it will not work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm...heard that somewhere